# Get Memory usage in IIS logging

Tags: file, iis, iis-10

I am diagnosing some api on the server, and I am using the IIS log but what it offers me is fine but I need two more variables that are the use of Memory and processor, I have researched and I find nothing that helps me to place those fields additional in the IIS log. Currently it shows me this and a field that I add

```
date time s-sitename s-computername s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs-version cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) cs-host sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status sc-bytes cs-bytes time-taken x-perfomance

2020-02-13 19:54:14 W3SVC1 usuarioFake ::1 GET /api/fake/prueba api-version=1 0 - ::1 HTTP/1.1 PostmanRuntime/7.22.0 - localhost 200 0 0 1638 330 4422 x-perfomance
```

Comment: IIS logging only records request/response, so things like processor/memory usage are out of scope. You won't be able to log them.

Comment: As lex says, the IIS logs will just log the request related information, it will not log the memory usage, the memory usage is the whole application processn, not just one process.